# Python Game of Life, only alive cells is in the corners

Tags: python, nested-lists, conways-game-of-life

I'm currently working on making a Game of Life program (UNI related, beginner course), by using nested lists.
However I can't seem to get the update() method to work properly, I've no clue what's wrong. The generation of the first board is okay, but the update leaves only the cornercells alive, and the rest dead.

All methodcalls in this class originates from other .py files, which works well.

```
from random import randint
from cell import *



class Spillebrett:


  def __init__(self, rows, columns):
    self.genNumber = 0
    self._rows = rows
    self._columns = columns
    self._grid = []
    for i in range(self._rows):
        self._grid.append([])
        for j in range(self._columns):
            self._grid[i].append(cell())
    self.generate()


  def drawBoard(self):
    for i in self._grid:
        print(" ".join(map(str, i)))
    print()

   #Method updates genNumber, checks if cells are alive or dead and updates the board accordingly
   #Currently only yield board with corner-cells alive
  def updateBoard(self):
    self.genNumber += 1
    toLive = []
    toDie = []
    for x, row in enumerate(self._grid):
        for y, cell in enumerate(rad):
            if cell.areAlive() is True:
                counter = len(self.findNeighbour(x, y))
                if counter < 2 or counter > 3:
                    toDie.append(cell)
                elif counter == 2 or counter == 3:
                    toLive.append(cell)
            elif cell.areAlive() is False:
                counter = len(self.findNeighbour(x, y))
                if counter == 3:
                    toLive.append(cell)
    for i in toDie:
            i.setDead()
    for i in toLive:
            i.setAlive()
    return self.genNumber

   #Code given by Uni
  def generate(self):
    for i in range(self._rows):
        for j in range(self._columns):
            rand = randint(0, 3)
            if rand == 3:
                self._grid[i][j].setAlive()

   #Code given by Uni
  def findNeighbour(self, row, column):
    neighbourList = []
    for i in range(-1, 2):
        for j in range(-1, 2):
            neighbourRow = rad + i
            neighbourcolumn = column + j
            if(neighbourRow == rad and neighbourcolumn == column) is not True:
                if(neighbourRow < 0 or neighbourcolumn < 0 or neighbourRow >
                self._rows - 1 or neighbourcolumn > self._columns - 1) is not True:
                    neighbourList.append(self._grid[neighbourRow][neighbourcolumn])
    return neighbourList

def findAllAlive(self):
    self._alive = 0
    for i in range(self._rows):
        for j in range(self._columns):
            if self._grid[i][j].areAlive() is True:
                self._alive += 1
    return self._alive
```

Comment: "All methodcalls in this class originates from other .py files, which works well." huh? Also, please please please never do `from cell import *`. That is only acceptable for `itertools` :)

Comment: Meaning, this class uses methods from other classes such as the method setAlive(), badly written comment by me. Of course, not all methods, but some methods would be a better way to write it. That's what we've been taught, but is there any reason why it doesn't work well? And is the only other way to import method by method?
Thanks for the input btw!

Comment: You mean you are using *objects* of some user-defined type that happens to have the class definition in another file? Yes, that's totally normal. In fact, it almost impossible to do anything useful *without using objects of other types in your class*. I just didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. Just a little lost in translation I guess (english' not my first language).

Comment: This may only be marginally helpful but I'd recommend creating known/working sample input, a unit test, and then stepping through each line, line-by-line to see what the issue is.

Comment: Since SOME cells are alive (mainly only those where max neighbours can be 3), its probably an error around `counter = len(self.findNeighbour(x, y))` i'd say. Have you tried looking at whats actually the value of counter while running?

Comment: When printing the counter within the for-loops, the counter prints all the neighbours, and not the living neighbours as it should.
Any tips to how only get the neighbouring cells that's alive, only?
If it was unclear, in an empty board (5x5), the counter returns (for the first row): 35553